# subtract time away from a php date time

Tags: php

I have a report I built but the problem is the datetimes in the database for the 3 major events are the same as the system processes then so fast, there is no easy way about it as I aggregate data from 4 servers into one jquery datatable and sort by date time decending.

So my question is how can I take a variable in PHP (string of mysql format date time), and reduce it by 1 second?

Comment: Why not just organise the entries by their ID?

Comment: Do as Kolink says, but if you insist on taking a second off, use `$minus_a_second = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtottime(YOUR_MYSQL_DATE) - 1)`

Comment: Kolink, As I said, I am aggregating data for diff servers, these 3 entries all have completely separate identity handling. This is the only way to do it. As for the vote downs I really do not see why. It is a question that I could find no repetition of!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dognose answer is fine. Find below a method using [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).
For those who are not too confident about strtotime  :-)

```
$string = "2013-06-26 18:00:00";

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $string);
$date->sub(new DateInterval('PT1S'));//substract 1 sec

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //print : 2013-06-26 17:59:59
```

Doc about "PT1S" [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) (this can be read as Period Time 1 second)

Comment: This is the better solution I think.

Answer (score 1):

use `date` along with `strtotime` should do the trick:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php

```
$string = "2013-06-26 18:00:00"; //can have any (valid) format

$subSeconds = 1;

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($string . " - {$subSeconds} second"));
echo $date."<br />"; //2013-06-26 17:59:59
```